# socket.io connects with same socket id

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

my socket creates problem when frontend loads before the server,
My problems are

1.I get same the socketid from the cookies of multiple clients

2.I get only one client who is connected with multiple socketids from the server

3.When I get this problem, my API calls will not work and I won't get any data from my database

I also get this problem when I restart the server, and when I refresh the frontend multiple times with different clients

my server side code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
express = require("express");
app = express();
bodyParser = require("body-parser");
cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
cors = require("cors");
user = require("./routes/user");
message = require("./routes/message");
http = require("http");
server = http.createServer(app);
io = require("socket.io")(server);
var userdata = require("./controllers/user");

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("DB CONNECTED");
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/use", user);
app.use("/use", message);

let users = [];

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("done", () => {
    let userdata = require("./controllers/user");
    console.log("connected");
    userdata.userdata &&
      users.push({ userid: userdata.userdata._id, socketid: socket.id });
    console.log(users);
  });

  socket.broadcast.emit("message");
  socket.on("more", function (c) {
    console.log(c.a, c.b);
    let d = users.find((s) => s.userid === c.b);
    if (d) {
      return io.to(d.socketid).emit("message", c);
    }
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(socket.id);
    if (users) {
      for (let e = 0; users.length; e++) {
        if (users[e] && users[e].socketid === socket.id) {
          return users.splice(e, 1);
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(users);
    return console.log("disconnected");
  });
});
// app.use();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`app is running at ${port}`);
});
```

I found that my problem is caused by **userdata**, when I had deleted everything related to **userdata**, I didn't get any problem even when the server is reloaded.

Here **userdata** comes from a middileware called **isSignedIn**,this middleware is called before every API call from this webpage, so **userdata** gets updated frequently by the frontend code.This is my **isSignedIn** function

```
exports.isSignedIn = async (req, res, next) => {
  const header = req.headers["authorization"];
  const token = header && header.split(" ")[1];
  if (!token) return res.json("no token");
  jwt.verify(token, "jsdhbcjsd", (err, User) => {
    if (err) return res.json(`${err}  not signedin`);
    req.User = User;
    exports.userdata = User;
    next();
  });
};
```

I tried to call **isSignedIn()** instead of importing **userdata**, which would be lot better, but I was getting an error from the **headers**, so I couldn't call this function.

error I get when I call this function **isSignedIn()**

```
Promise {
  <rejected> TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined
      at exports.isSignedIn (D:\message\backend\controllers\user.js:86:22)
```

it tells about this line

```
 const header = req.headers["authorization"];
```

I made sure that the socket gets connected in the frontend only after calling the APIs using await,so that the **userdata** gets updated before connecting to the socket.I had tested it in the console,socket gets connected only after calling APIs

```
async componentDidMount() {
  //my API calls
      await this.friends(token);
      await this.findfriends(token);

  //connect the socket
      this.start();
      this.recieve();
 }}
```

My frontend code

```
const client = require("socket.io-client");
var socket
export default class Home extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.start = this.start.bind(this);
    this.send = this.send.bind(this);
    this.recieve = this.recieve.bind(this);
    this.friends= this.friends.bind(this);
    this.findfriends= this.findfriends.bind(this);
 }
 start(){
 socket=client("http://localhost:8000");
 }
 send(){
 socket.emit("more", c)
 }
 recieve(){
 socket.on("message", c)
 }
 async componentDidMount() {
  //my API calls
      await this.friends(token);
      await this.findfriends(token);

  //connect the socket
      this.start();
      this.recieve();
 }}    

 render(){
 return(my data)
 }
}
```

Comment: What is this `let userdata = require("./controllers/user");` doing?  You are getting the exact same `userdata` with that statement for every single user.  So, when you then do `users.push({ userid: userdata.userdata._id, socketid: socket.id });`, you're pushing the exact same `userid` property every time.

Comment: Also, in this `for (e = 0; users.length; ++e) {`, change to `for (let e = 0; e < users.length; ++e) {` so you aren't using an accidental/implicit/undeclared global in your `for` loop and so you have proper bounds on your loop.

Comment: After reading your comments, I had deleted everything related to userdata from the server.I didn't get this problem when I refresh my server, I'm getting same socketids in the frontend only when i delete the cookies before the server reloads .The userdata is from a middleware called isSighnedin, which is called before every API of this page, and Its redirected to this page only when a client signs in.Im importing userdata because, I can't call that function here because of some header issues.

Comment: my isSigned function `exports.isSignedIn = async (req, res, next) => {
  const header = req.headers["authorization"];
  const token = header && header.split(" ")[1];
  if (!token) return res.json("no token");
  jwt.verify(token, "jsdhbcjsd", (err, User) => {
    if (err) return res.json('${err}  not signedin');
    req.User = User;
    exports.userdata = User;
    next();
  });
};`

Comment: Multi-line code is not readable in comments.  Please add the code to your question using the "edit" link and then post a comment that you updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking for a while about requesting headers,which isn't possible, I thought, why couldn't I get userid from the socket when just it gets connected, then I tried this code, it worked perfectly fine

client side

```
 start = () => {
    socket = client("http://localhost:8000");
    socket.on("connect", () => {
      return socket.emit("userinfo", this.state.User._id);
    });
  };
```

server side

```
 socket.on("userinfo", function (user) {
    users.push({ userid: user, socketid: socket.id });
    console.log("C O N N E C T E D");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reassign `exports.userdata = User;` in middleware. That will affect every single request that uses those exports so they will all end up looking at the same `userdata`, no matter which user they are.  That's the source of your confusion.  There's only one `exports` object for each module and everyone who uses that module sees the same `exports` object.  So, you can't use `exports` for request-specific data.

I see you are already assigning `req.User = User`.  That is an appropriate place to put request-specific data and other users of that data in the processing of the request should get the data from `req.User`, not from the exported object. That will keep the data separate for each request and each user.

Comment: I will get `req.User ` only after executing `isSignedIn()`, else it will be `null`, but im not able to call this function.I'm able to use it as a middleware for my routes, and use `req.User` in my route function.`router.post("/message", isSignedIn, createmessage);
`.Here I'm able to use `req.User` in `createmessage()`.I get headers undefined when i call `isSignedIn()`, and `request` undefined when i call `isSignedIn(request,response,next)`, after installing `resquest`, I get `response` undefined. There is no npm to install `response`

Comment: I tried to get headers without using `isSignedIn`, but I'm not able to get it without using a router

Comment: @ram -  The ONLY place you can use the user you looked up is in a route handler for that same request..  That data belongs to this request.  So, you use it in a route that is after your middleware.  This is what middleware is for and is how it works.  You can't takes some route-specific or user-specific data and stuff it in a module variable somewhere and then use it later.  That would make a server that would only work for ONE user.